# Powershell sql server module 2017 manual install

Tags: sql-server, powershell-3.0

Just installed sql server 2017 RTM. After that I installed SSMS version 17. Funny enough this won't install the powershell module but you have to install it from PowerShell Gallery. Now my servers of course (being an enterprise environment) have no direct connection to the internet and not even the management computers in that domain have. From the Powershell Gallery website I was not able to manually install the powershell module. Question is do anybody here managed to have latest sql server powershell module installed for sql server 2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not in an environment to test this but one method would be to install the module on a computer/server that does have access to the internet, download and install it there, locate the module, and then copy it to the other server and import it. So, something like:

On the other computer (with internet access):

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
(Get-Module -ListAvailable SqlServer).Path
```

Go to the path and copy the file(s) to the same location on the other server. Then, on the other server, and run:

```
Import-Module -Name SqlServer
```

This *assumes* that both hosts are running the same version of Powershell; or at least compatible ones.